# Is EBO redundant?

Tags: opengl

So I understand how EBO and VAO work, how to make them, but I don't know if it would be more efficient to use EBO or just VAO. As far as I understand, the EBO is usefull when you have repeating vertices, but what if my vertex data has apart from say position and normal a texture position(maybe even animation related data or something else). Then it will be very unlikely for all of them to match and get better memory using the EBO(which would add for each triangle 3 more ints). Would it be better in such a case to use just the VAO and not bind it to an EBO or is there some work around this, like setting the indices of the triangles in an EBO and the texture position(or whatever data it may also contain) in a different one?

Comment: "*Then it will be very unlikely for all of them to match and get better memory using the EBO*" Have you actually looked at actual mesh data to confirm this? Also, consider that meshes (and textures) can be designed by the artist to allow for more vertex reuse.

Comment: In my case, I only have triangles and quads in meshes and vertices in the same position may refer to different objects, that are most likely to have different textures assigned to them and different normals. I am sorry for the confusion, forgot to add that in the post

Comment: There's an "edit" button for adding information to your question. Also, your question now seems to be "I have a very specialized use case that EBOs don't seem to be a good fit for. Why do EBOs exist if they don't work for my use case?"

Comment: Even for a single quad with just positions, you have 6 vertices * 3 floats = 18byte without EBO, but just 4 vertices * 3 floats + 6 int = 18 byte. This means that even for a quad without any additional attributes, the memory consumption of EBO/no EBO are the same. With every attribute added, you start to save memory with the EBO.

Comment: If you are worried that the space of indices could outweight the space saved in the VBO, just compute it as @BDL did, but take into account that you are not only limited to 32-bit ints for the indices. You could use 16-bit, or even 8-bit, integers if you are not going to use that many indices. Obviously, if no vertex will be repeated, there will be no memory saved by using EBO, but that depends on your particular mesh, what is it?